# Move Owl-Carousel with navigation multiple slides at a time of click

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

Is there any way we can move multiple items in owl carousel with navigation click.

Like this in the demo

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Powerful-Customizable-jQuery-Carousel-Slider-OWL-Carousel/demos/custom.html

i want this in navigation link there is a option in slick slider but i want this in owl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should include `slideBy: [number]` or `slideBy: 'page'` option, as they describe it on their [documentation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html#slideby).

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  items: 5,
  slideBy: 5
})
```

```css
.item {
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/css/docs.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <h4>1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>3</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>4</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>5</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>6</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>7</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>8</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>9</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>10</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>11</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>12</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```